# LU decomposition with pivoting

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to solve system of linear algebraic equations
                    `AX=B`,
where A is two-dimensional matrix and all elements of main diagonal are equal to zero.

*How to solve this problem?* 
Iterational methods are not applied in this case.

One way is LU Decomposition method with reordering rows of `A` to get entries in main diagonal are not zero using `permutation matrix`.
*How to quickly reorder rows of matrix or find permutation matrix?*

Note that matrix is very big and I have to write programm to solve SLAE in C# language, so I do not need any matlab or mathematica functions.
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this belongs here or over at cs.stackexchange.com...

Comment: What do you mean with _two-dimensional_ matrix? Normally one would interpret that as a $2\times2$ matrix, but this seems to contradict "matrix is very big". Do you just means that the matrix can be written in a two-dimensional layout? This is true for _all_ matrices, so if you mean that just drop the phrase.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It may be a misuse of terminology, as I have seen the term 'matrix' applied to higher dimensional arrays of data in the computational sciences.

Comment: I mean usual two-dimensional matrix nxn, with n > 500000. like this http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_264sc_gncA4/SiEOApq5oaI/AAAAAAAAAVE/DG_mb6OI7r0/s400/Session8-two-dim+array.png

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Use an array, `p[]` to hold the row permutations. The permutation vector

```
p =[ 3,2,1,4,5,6]
```

indicates that the row corresponding to row 1 of the permuted matrix is row 3 of the original matrix, and row 3 corresponds to row 1. I.e. row 1 and 3 have been swapped.

Then use `p` to index into the rows of your permuted matrix matrix `A`. i.e. if you want to update the `i`'th row, you would index as

```
A[p[i]][...] = ...
```

This effectifely swaps the two rows, with you only interchanging 2 numbers, rather than the entire two rows.

The same idea can be used for full pivotting, where the columns are permuted also.

**Added later:** Implementation details

Initially the `p` array is initialised as an unpermuted matrix, e.g.

```
p = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

If the algorithm then requires you to swap rows 1 and 3, interchange the row indices in positions 1 and 3. e.g.

```
p = [3,2,1,4,5,6];
```

If you then have to swap rows 2 and 3, interchange the row indices in positions 2 and 3. e.g.

```
p = [3,1,2,4,5,6];
```

The array `p` holds the indices into the rows of the matrix `A`. Instead of swapping the entire rows of A, by using `p` as a row index to `A`, you can swap entire rows with a single swap, rather than $n$ swaps which are required to swap the entire rows.

Comment: I asked about how to permute array rows, in your case how do you create permutation vector p = [3,2,1,4,5,6]? Why not p = [3,4,5,2,1,3] for example?

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov See my edit with implementation details.